# Could not locate aapt. Please ensure you have the Android buildtools installed FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have a problem with the application that I am trying to compile, the system generates the .apk for me, but it does not manually install the application on the device that I am debugging

[image: This appears in the visual studio code console]

The console gives me the following message:

```
Could not locate aapt. Please ensure you have the Android buildtools installed.
Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).
Exited (sigterm)
```

I'm new to flutter I don't know what it could be, someone help me please, I'll be grateful